# Comparing Counts of the same column MySQL to get a percentage

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, percentage

What I need to do is the following:

Get a percentage of all class surveys in this program where the answer to question 1 was greater than 3.

I have a table that contains a huge dataset of classroom surveys. The issue is that GENE01, for example, might have 5 surveys done on it from 5 different students; so I have 4 classes, but 50 surveys associated with them.

So currently, I'm running two queries to accomplish this task, but I'd like for it to be one single query. Here are the two queries I'm looking to combine.

```
-- Query 1
SELECT COUNT(survey_ID) as total 
FROM survey_Table
WHERE courseName LIKE 'GENE01'
   OR courseName LIKE 'GENE02'
   OR courseName LIKE 'GENE03'
   OR courseName LIKE 'GENE04'
GROUP BY survey_ID WITH ROLLUP
; 
-- Query 2
SELECT COUNT (survey_ID) as newTotal
FORM survey_Table
WHERE courseName LIKE 'GENE01' AND question1 > 3
   OR courseName LIKE 'GENE02' AND question1 > 3
   OR courseName LIKE 'GENE03' AND question1 > 3
   OR courseName LIKE 'GENE04' AND question1 > 3
GROUP BY survey_ID WITH ROLLUP
;
```

Then I manually take a calculator from my desk and do newTotal / total * 100. I can't figure out the sub query (or whatever you need to do) to accomplish this simple task. The issue I guess I'm having is I don't know how to compare counts of the same column.

Thanks everyone, and sorry I'm pretty new to MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is a possible approach:

```
 SELECT s.survey_ID
      , SUM(1)                AS total
      , SUM(s.question1 > 3)  AS newTotal
   FROM survey_Table s
  WHERE s.courseName IN ('GENE01','GENE02','GENE03','GENE04')
  GROUP
     BY s.survey_ID
   WITH ROLLUP
```

Note the condition `s.question1 > 3` is MySQL shorthand. MySQL evaluates that and returns 1 for TRUE, returns 0 for FALSE, and NULL if its null.

That's almost equivalent to the more portable ANSI-standards compliant:

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN s.question1 > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS newTotal
```

There's a difference is in handling of NULL values.

A more precise rewrite of `SUM(s.question1 > 3)` would be

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN s.question1 > 3 THEN 1 WHEN s.question1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 0 END)
```

For each row returned, the expression inside the `SUM()` aggregate is evaluated. `1` always evaluates to `1`.

Feel free to omit `survey_ID` from the SELECT list. Normally when we do a `GROUP BY foo` we're interested in which result row is associated with which `foo`.

---

The question asks about getting a "percentage". We can do division in an  expression in the `SELECT` list.  But I don't think the "`with rollup`" is going to get you what you what you are expecting.

Here's an example:

```
 SELECT SUM(1)                AS total
      , SUM(s.question1 > 3)  AS newTotal

      , 100.0
      * SUM(s.question1 > 3) 
      / SUM(1)                 AS percentage

   FROM survey_Table s
  WHERE s.courseName IN ('GENE01','GENE02','GENE03','GENE04')
```

In this example, I've opted to omit a `GROUP BY` clause. So this will return a single overall total row, which would get us an overall percentage. (If we used a `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`, the percentage would get added. And likely that's not the result we're after.)

Comment: my thoughts exactly

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for taking the time to explain everything!

Comment: @KennyWilson: having tools like this in our SQL toolbelts is a good thing... conditional aggregation is a common pattern, but one which isn't covered in the "Learn SQL In 1 Week"-type tutorial. The Reference Manual gives us the syntax elements. It's knowing how to wield that syntax to achieve the results we want... that's what earns us the wand and tall pointy hat with stars.

Answer (score 0):

You could join both the query   by survey_id

```
    select t1.survey_ID, t2.newTotal/t1.total 
    from (
    SELECT survey_ID, COUNT (survey_ID) as newTotal
    FORM survey_Table
    WHERE courseName LIKE 'GENE01' AND question1 > 3
       OR courseName LIKE 'GENE02' AND question1 > 3
       OR courseName LIKE 'GENE03' AND question1 > 3
       OR courseName LIKE 'GENE04' AND question1 > 3
    GROUP BY survey_ID ) 
    INNER JOIN (

    SELECT survey_ID, COUNT(survey_ID) as total 
    FROM survey_Table
    WHERE courseName LIKE 'GENE01'
       OR courseName LIKE 'GENE02'
       OR courseName LIKE 'GENE03'
       OR courseName LIKE 'GENE04'
    GROUP BY survey_ID ) t2. ON t1.survey_ID = t2.survey_ID
```